# nil while parsing firebase in swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to parse value from firebase to my dictionary:

```
for rest in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [FIRDataSnapshot] {

                guard let restDict = rest.value as? [String: String] else {
                    continue
                }
                if (restDict["uid"] != FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid && (restDict["userCity"])! == "SomeCity"){

                    self.users.updateValue(restDict["userImgLink"]!, forKey: restDict["userName"]!)
                        print(self.users["userName"])

                    }
            }
```

And here is my dict declaration:

```
var users: [String : String] = [:]
```

restDict value returns me an Optional("somestring"), but elf.users["userName"] returns nil. How could I get a real value in my dict? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd suggest to do some debugging and check what are the values of all values in `restDict`, it would be nice to add one as a code snippet...

Comment: Are you sure that key userName exists ?

Comment: @Anuraj Yes, it returns me Optional("name")

Answer (score 0):

In the below line you are trying to set the value `restDict["userImgLink"]!` for key `restDict["userName"]!`, so the key will be the value of `restDict["userName"]!` and not `"userName"`.

```
 self.users.updateValue(restDict["userImgLink"]!, forKey: restDict["userName"]!)
```

but while printing you are trying to get the value for `"userName"` key , which will be nil.

Comment: Thanks, and what should I write in a such case? If I delete "!", I couldn't build my app.